# onClick when placed in a tag being added in variable called HTML in JavaScript file is non-functional

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, tags

I am creating a table using `javascript`.  I have created the `HTML DOM` using html variable within my `javascript`file.

I am using a tag in this `DOM`to generate `onClick` event for some functionality. i.e. a `javascript` function is being called on `onClick` event. But this a tag is non-functional, as it outputs the name of function itself.

I have even tried out `href="#"`, and `onkeypress`instead of `onClick` is not allowed in first case

> Invalid character

And the same problem persists in `onkeypress` as in `onClick` i.e. the function name itself outputs along with table values.

```
myData.forEach(function(value){
        html += "<tr>";
        for(mykeys in value){
          html += "<td>" +"<a href="#" onkeydown=(e)=> compareMe(e,key,value[mykeys])>" +"<span>" +value[mykeys] +"</span>" +"</a>" +"</td>"
        }
       html += "</tr>";
     });
```

Only table values should appear in the output. But here the called `javascript` function attached with `onClick` event itself appears in the output, of course, the tables values are also printed. No error is shown in the console.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: You have a syntax error your `onkeydown` does not have `"` around the function. Can you supply some sample data. and I am sure someone will help.

Answer (score 0):

This code has a number of problems. I'll start with a few.

One, you are not escaping your quote marks.

```
variable = "something "another thing" yet another thing";
```

Should end up as a syntax error, because you can't include quotes inside of a quoted string without escaping them with a slash. it should be written as...

```
variable = "something \"another thing\" yet another thing";
```

Second, you are putting your function into the value onkeypress, without quotes.

```
onkeydown=(e)=> compareMe(e,key,value[mykeys])>
```

Should result in invalid mark up for your html. It should be written as...

```
onkeydown="(e)=> compareMe(e,key,value[mykeys])">
```

But if you are putting this last part into a quoted string, don't forget to escape the quote marks.

Comment: Done as per your syntax:

Comment: myData.forEach(function(value){
       html += "<tr>";
         for(mykeys in value){
           html += "<td>" 
           html+= "<a onClick=\"(e)=> \"compareMe(e,key,value[mykeys])\">" 
          html += "<span>" +value[mykeys] +"</span>" 
           html += "</a>" 
           html += "</td>"
        }
       html += "</tr>";
      });
          html += "</table>";
     html += "</div>";

     function compareMe(value){
      if(value==="2"){
      html += "<td>" +"X" +"</td>";
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += html;
        return html;
      }

Comment: ERROR:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: @HDhindsa well the code you pasted doesn't have semi colons at  the end of code lines, so that might be your issue. hard to parse the rest by looking at this unformatted comment though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape double quotes inside you string with a backslash. See [Special Characters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) for reference. Also the [onclick attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) needs to be in double quotes.

```
myData.forEach(function (value) {
    html += "<tr>";
    for (mykeys in value) {
        html += "<td><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"(e)=>compareMe(e, key, value[mykeys])\"><span>" + value[mykeys] + "</span></a></td>";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
});
```